# Creating a global variable versus passing the variable between functions

Tags: python, scope

I am iterating over a list and for each row in the list I need call a function to read the row and act upon it. Should I make the list a global variable or should I pass each row to the different functions?

The functions a,b,c do not modify the row of the list, they just read values and make some decisions.

Option A

```
def iterate_over_list():
    list_ = [ 1,2,3 ]
    for each_row in list_:
        func_a(each_row)
        func_b(each_row)
        func_c(each_row)

def func_a(each_row):
    read_the_row__value_and_make_a_decision

def func_b(each_row):
    read_the_row__value_and_make_a_decision

def func_c(each_row):
    read_the_row__value_and_make_a_decision
```

Option B

```
global list_

def iterate_over_list():
    list_ = [ 1,2,3 ]
    for each_row in list_:
        func_a()
        func_b()
        func_c()

def func_a():
    read_the_row__value_and_make_a_decision

def func_b():
    read_the_row__value_and_make_a_decision

def func_c():
    read_the_row__value_and_make_a_decision
```

Comment: General rule of thumb: global *variable* =
‘There’s likely a better approach, rethink the solution.’

Comment: I am concerned about the memory footprint, since if I do not use a global variable, Python will make a copy each time I call a function. So I will end up with 10 copies for the 10 functions. I am not modifying the variable, just reading it.

Comment: Not sure if your comment was in response to mine; but I’ll just mention that whoever maintains the code behind you (even if not in this case, future cases) they’ll be highly grateful for a design *not* involving *any* globals.  (Trust me!)  :-)

Comment: Are your rows enormous? Why are you so concerned about passing a row to each function?

Comment: @BruceBanner Python will only make a copy if the parameter is immutable like a string (and even then they may point to a common memory address).  Otherwise most containers and objects have reference semantics.

Comment: The rows are not enormous. I just don't want to iterate again and again over a list. If I need to make 10 decisions per row of a list, where-in each decision is made by a function, I want to iterate once over the list, and for each row, call the 10 functions and make decisions. It's more effecient than iterating 10 times over the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @S3DEV noted, you should avoid using global variables unless *strictly* necessary.

Assuming I'm following you correctly and each function only needs access to the row, rather than the whole list, option A is greatly preferred.

If you want each function to have access to `list_`, you can define the functions inside `iterate_over_list` after `list_` is defined.